# VSCode when I read information from a text file for python, it also deleted everything from the text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Here's the code I use to read from the file

```
def load_leaderboard(file_name, leader_names, leader_scores):

  leaderboard_file = open(file_name, "r")  # need to create the file ahead of time in same folder

  # use a for loop to iterate through the content of the file, one line at a time
  # note that each line in the file has the format "leader_name,leader_score" for example "Pat,50"
  for line in leaderboard_file:
    leader_name = ""
    leader_score = ""    
    index = 0

    # TODO 1: use a while loop to read the leader name from the line (format is "leader_name,leader_score")
    while (line[index] != ","):
        leader_name = leader_name + line[index] 
        index = index + 1
    print("leader name is " + leader_name)  


    # TODO 2: add the leader name to the list
    leader_names.append(leader_name)

    
    # TODO 3: read the player score using a similar loop'
    index += 1
    while(line[index] != '\n'):
        leader_score += line[index]
        index += 1
    print('The score for this person is:' + leader_score)

    
    # TODO 4: add the player score to the list


  leaderboard_file.close()
```

When this code runs it works correctly, only once it reads everything from the text file it deletes all the information from the text file itself. I thought it would be fine since i put the open() function on readonly. But its not, how do i keep it from deleting the information from the original file?

Comment: There is no way the quoted code deletes info in the open file. You probably have some other code. As a side comment it’s very ineffecient how you parse leader name & score.just split the string by comma.

Comment: search your code for `open(xxx, "w")` lines